# FancyTree > Expand parents to an active subnode

Tags: fancytree

I have a list converted as FancyTree. The FancyTree has been set to activeVisible:true which means imho that the tree containing an active node will be expanded from the active node up to the topmost parent. But this isn't working so I think I miss something but can't figure out what this can be.

The init:

```
$("div[id^=msctree]").fancytree({
    checkbox: true,
    selectMode: 1,
    activeVisible: true,
    extensions: ['contextMenu'],
    contextMenu: {
        menu: {
            'edit': { 'name': 'Edit', 'icon': 'edit' },
        },
        actions: function(node, action, options) {
            if ( action == "edit" ) {
                ...someAction...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The list:

```
<div id="msctree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   Topmost parent
   <ul>
    <li data-active="true" data-expanded="true">
     Subnode
     <ul>
       <li>List with further dubs</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

The li with data-active="true" and data-expanded="true" is expanded but the topmost parent is not which I think is a wrong behavior because I has set activeVisible to true.
Why is that? How can I configure the fancetree() plugin to do what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FancyTree has a built in feature to do so but it seems not to work. So the developer of this nice plugin opened an issue for that. Until the issue is solved one can use my workaround.

```
init: function(event, data) {
        var activeJumpNode = data.tree.getActiveNode();
        if ( activeJumpNode ) {
            var treeObj = $("div[id^=msctree]").fancytree("getTree");
            var jumpToNode = treeObj.findFirst(function(node) {
                return node === activeJumpNode;
            });
            jumpToNode.setActive();
            jumpToNode.setFocus();
            $(treeObj.$container).focus();
        }           
    }
```

This expands all parents to an active subnode.